# mongod cannot execute in ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, binary, execution

I am installing mongodb on ubuntu terminal from this url [(http://mongojs.org/install-mongodb-ubuntu-11-04-natty)](http://mongojs.org/install-mongodb-ubuntu-11-04-natty)

I am on the step where you type in ./mongod

when I type that I get the following: bash: ./mongod cannot execute binary file error

can someone help me get over this obstacle? thanks.

Comment: Is that the limit of your error? What is the output of "ldd /usr/bin/mongod" and "/usr/bin/mongod -vvvv"?

Comment: ldd: no such file or directory<br />-ww:<br />ldd: .-ww no such file or directory

Comment: Where is mongod installed? "which mongod" What happens when you run it in verbose mode?

Comment: can you explain what verbose mode means? it is installed in /home/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.6

Comment: With the "-vvvv" option above. So run  /home/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.6/bin/mongod -vvvv please. Also ldd should be in /usr/bin or maybe /usr/sbin. Can you also run "/usr/bin/ldd /home/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.6/bin/mongod"?

Answer (score 1):

My only suggestion would be to check you're using the correct version (32-bit vs 64-bit). The link provided in the tutorial is 64-bit, which won't work if you're using a 32-bit machine.

Comment: I have 64 bit and I really don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by an invalid installation. Follow the following steps on ubuntu to install Mongodb properly:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

With this, you can now start your local mongo instance. Make sure to update your config file to change your data directory to where you want to have the DB files stored.

Comment: Did you actually read the link user1522901 posted? Those are the actual steps he/she claims to have followed.

Comment: Mark, based on the error, I think it was safe to assume he did not use the package manager, but rather the manual option in the link he provided. It seems to me like he's missing some dependencies which would be resolved by installing using apt-get.

Comment: Well he/she said that he/she did. I don't think apt-get will resolve that error. Regardless of that, you should have added it as a comment, not an answer.